# Does SchemaCrawler Support Salesforce?

Tags: schemacrawler

I'm currently using schemacrawler to extract metadata for MySQL and MSSQL types of source systems.

But curious to know whether it supports Salesforce Data? From the [docs](https://www.schemacrawler.com/database-support.html) I do not see the option though. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/) with Salesforce explicitly. However, SchemaCrawler will work with any JDBC-compliant JDBC driver. I would suggest that you find a commercially available Salesforce JDBC driver than a free one.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: I just tested with the cdata JDBC driver for Salesforce, and SchemaCrawler works fine. Try using https://www.cdata.com/drivers/salesforce/download/jdbc/

Comment: Thank you @Sualeh for the quick response.  I will definitely test this and get back to you

Comment: also @Sualeh could you please confirm what're the params you passed for the schemacrawler shell script ? If you can let me know from this -> ( schemacrawler.sh --server="$1" --host="$2" --database="$3" --user="$4" --password="$5" --port="$6" --log-level=INFO --info-level=standard -c script --sort-tables=false --script "$7")

Comment: @Kulasangar - if this is going to be a back and forth, please take it to https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/discussions

Comment: thanks @Sualeh. I've created a discussion on this https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/discussions/497